# getting value from textbox

Tags: php

I have following code:

```
     <input type="hidden" name="qz_id" value="<?=$quizid; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="s_id" value="<?=$s_id; ?>" />

 <? if($num!=$i) {?><input type="submit" value="Next" /><? } ?>
 <? if($num==$i) {?><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Finish" /><? } ?>
```

This is the part of whole page of code. What i am trying to do is insert these values in database. Can you tell me how can i get value of textbox "answer" and store it in a php variable? I want to insert this value into database once user press next or finish?

Here is the form:

```
<form id="formresp" method="post" action="respond.php?quiz_id=<?=$quizid ?>" name="register" onsubmit='return ValidateForm(this)'>
```

Also i triend $_POST['answer'] it is not working

Comment: all posted vars are in the super global $_POST.  Also I suggest not using short hand tags.

Comment: "how can i get value of textbox "answer"" you didnt inlude that code so impossible for me to know

Comment: also I think you want this to be <? if($num<$i) {?>

Comment: sorry my bad... just new to this so did not knew you need to see the form. But i posted it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use $_REQUEST['answer'];. I sort of a $_POST and $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

All form variables are stored in either `$_GET` or `$_POST` depending on how you post the form.